# flex error 1137: Incorrect number of arguments. Expected no more than 0

Tags: database, apache-flex, search, flash-builder

I am trying to create a mobile app in flash builder. I wanted to use the text field to search the list but I keep getting this error in my function list_creation complete handler

edit: 
I am using wamp php server to retrieve data in my program and then view them, as list  wordsService2 class was generated automatically when I created linked my database.

> error 1137: Incorrect number of arguments. Expected no more than 0.

This is what program looks like:
[image]

```
<s:View>
<fx:Script>
<![CDATA[
    import mx.events.FlexEvent;

    protected function list_creationCompleteHandler():void
    {
        getAllWordsResult.token = wordsService2.getAllWords(txt.text); 
    }

]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
    <s:CallResponder id="getAllWordsResult"/>
    <wordsservice2:WordsService2 id="wordsService2"/>
</fx:Declarations>

<s:actionContent>
    <s:Button label="Search" click="list_creationCompleteHandler()"/>
</s:actionContent>

<s:navigationContent>
    <s:TextInput id="txt" width="242"/>
</s:navigationContent>

<s:List id="list" width="100%" height="100%"
         labelField="term">
    <s:AsyncListView list="{getAllWordsResult.lastResult}"/>
</s:List>
</s:View>
```

getallwords

```
public function getAllWords() {

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->connection, "SELECT * FROM $this->tablename");        
    $this->throwExceptionOnError();

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $this->throwExceptionOnError();

    $rows = array();

    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $row->id, $row->term, $row->defin, $row->term1, $row->defin1);

    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
      $rows[] = $row;
      $row = new stdClass();
      mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $row->id, $row->term, $row->defin, $row->term1, $row->defin1);
    }

    mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);
    mysqli_close($this->connection);

    return $rows;
}
```

Comment: Didn't you have a previous question on this topic?  Did you delete it and repost it?  It is considered appropriate etiquette to edit your question to add more details; not to repost the question.

Comment: am new here , wont happen again ..thanks

Comment: I think we need to see your ActionScript code; however assuming it mirrors your server side API; the getAllWords() method does not accept any arguments and that is why you are getting the error.  I feel like I've said this multiple times already.

Answer (score 0):

WordsService2.getAllWords() does not take any arguments. You are calling it with a string; the content of the textinput. That's why you get the Error 1173.